# Why isn't $\ln^{\ln (x)}(x)$ defined for $(-\infty,1)$?

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I was taking a look at the following function:
$$f(x) = \ln^{\ln (x)}(x)$$
I see it's not defined in $\mathbb{R}$ for any $x \in (-\infty, 1)$. I understand why it's not defined in ${1}$, as $f(1)$ would be $0^0$.

However, why isn't it defined for $x\in(0,1)$?

If we let $x=\frac{1}{e}$, why don't we have $$f\left(\frac{1}{e}\right) = -1^{-1}= -1$$?

Comment: By default, the expression you have written is $\log \left( x ^{\log x} \right)$, which the rest of your discussion doesn't seem to be about.

Comment: I would argue that the parentheses are mandatory in order for the expression to be what you said. Without parentheses, the argument is just $x$, and hence the expression I wrote is equivalent to $\log^{\log(x)}(x).$ I have, however, edited it to clear ambiguity.

Comment: The argument to the logarithm is the entire *term* following "$\log$".  A term is ended by an un-nested addition, an un-nested subtraction, the end of the nesting containing the "$\log$", or the end of the entire expression.

Comment: Try $x = \frac1{2e}$ or $x=\frac12$ to see the issue with some of the other numbers in $(0,1)$.  You could try complex solutions, though even that is not simple

Comment: $f(1/\mathrm{e})$ is not $-1$ because you have defined $f$ with logarithms to the base $10$.

Comment: Where did I ever say it was base $10$? $\log x$ is base $e$.

Comment: No.  "$\ln$" is base $\mathrm{e}$.  "$\log$" is base $10$.  "$\log_b$" for $b>0$, $b \neq 1$ is base $b$.

Comment: I stand corrected if that's the case. In my undergrad calculus course, we have been taught that the notation $\log x$ is equivalent to $\ln x$ and that the logarithm base 10 is written as $\text{Log} x$. Wolfram Alpha seems to agree with me as well as it interprets $\log$ as the logarithm base $e$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha would be a very poor authority on notation given their many bizarre choices.  Perhaps better: Google search for "calculator".  You get a calculator with a "ln" button and a "log" button.  The TI-89 uses "LN" for log base e.  The HP-35s uses "LN" and "LOG".  And this notation is adequately documented [in](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/LogFunctions.aspx) [many](http://www.mclph.umn.edu/mathrefresh/logs.html) [places](https://www.britannica.com/science/logarithm).

Comment: Like I said, I stand corrected.

Comment: It actually depends on whose book you read. The symbol $\log$ with unspecified base is generally considered to be the common logarithm (base ten) except in sources that consider it the natural logarithm. The safe thing to do is to say up front what logarithm you're using, make the base explicit, or (as you've done) use a more specific function name such as $\ln$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = \mathrm{10}^{-1/2} = 0.316\dots \text{.}$  Then 
$$(\log (10^{-1/2}))^{\log (10^{-1/2})} = (-1/2)^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-1/2}}  \text{.}  $$
Since we are working in real numbers, we do not take square roots of negative numbers.

This occurs for every $x = 10^{-p/q}$ for $0 < p < q$ and even $q>0$.  This removes a dense subset of the interval $(0,1)$ from the domain.  There are still some points remaining in the domain in the interval $(0,1)$, but compactly writing down that set is infeasible.